# MVC-3 ASP.NET Shared Views-Redirect-Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, view, shared

I have a shared view called NotAuthorised in the folder 'Views/Shared'. I want to redirect the users to this view when they are not authorised to see the page.

Initially, this view was in a folder called Account. But I moved it into the Shared folder as I am not using the Account anymore. I have deleted the Account folder.

I used the following code to redirect:

```
public ActionResult NotAuthorised()
{  
   return RedirectToAction("NotAuthorised", "Account");
}
```

Now that I removed the Account folder, I'm trying to use

```
public ActionResult NotAuthorised()
{  
   return RedirectToAction("NotAuthorised", "Shared");
}
```

I am completely wrong by giving the folder name shared in the last line.

Could anyone tell me, what I am doing wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't redirect to a `View`, only to an `Action` of a `Controller`. You have to specify an controller action for your redirect and there you can render your shared view.

```
public class AuthorizeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult NotAuthorised()
    {  
       return View("NotAuthorised");
    }
}
```

and later redirect to this new action from within any other action method:

```
return RedirectToAction("NotAuthorised", "Authorize");
```

But you may not need this additional `Controller`. You could simply render the shared `View`

```
public ActionResult NotAuthorised()
{  
   return View("NotAuthorised");
}
```

Comment: Thank you, very much. Look forward for your answers.

Comment: I have used these two.                                           return View("~/Views/Shared/NotAuthorised.cshtml"); and return View("NotAuthorised"), both of them works.